Conditions on $m$ to show that $(am^2+1)^x+(bm^2-1)^y=(cm)^z$ has a unique solution
My question is: are there any method to obtain  Conditions on $m$ to show that $(am^2+1)^x+(bm^2-1)^y=(cm)^z$ has a unique solution? For example Terai has obtained the following result:When $m$ is odd, we suppose that
$m\equiv 1 (\mod 3); m \equiv 2 (\mod 5)$ or $m \equiv \pm 1;2 (\mod 7)$.
Then equation $$(4m^{2}+1)^{x}+(45m^{2}-1)^{y}=(5m)^{z}$$ has only the positive integer solution $(x;y;z) = (1;1;2)$.
Thank you.
